# user_likes permission not required BUG?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Facebook [says](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/page_fan/):

> To read the page_fan table you need
>
> - any valid access_token if it is public (visible to anyone on Facebook).
> - **user_likes permissions if querying the current user.**
> - friends_likes permissions if querying a user's friend.

I just ran this query in the [Graph Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer):

```
SELECT page_id FROM page_fan WHERE uid=me() AND page_id=105557426145540
```

... however I did **not** request **user_likes** permission and it (correctly) said that I have liked this page. Is this a bug?

Comment: And are your likes public? Per the first message

Comment: my default privacy is set to *friends* but does **it** refer to the like itself or the page?

Comment: The likes and interests section of your Facebook profile i believe, go to your profile, then likes, then edit a section, there's a privacy selector there for each section - I think 'Other Pages you like' covers the bulk of uncategorised pages

Comment: ah yes that worked, however it seems that there is no way to change the privacy setting for actual *fan pages*, just *likes and interests*.

Answer (score 0):

Igy:

> go to your profile, then likes, then edit a section, there's a privacy
>   selector there for each section - I think 'Other Pages you like'
>   covers the bulk of uncategorised pages

However, you can only manage the privacy of the likes in your profile. Any fan page (ie business page) that you like is automatically public.

For the purposes of my app, it's nice knowing that I won't have to ask for **user_like** permissions.

From the user perspective there are a few people not too happy about it...

https://www.facebook.com/MakeFanPagesPrivate

Comment: No, they're not automatically public, as far as I know every Page you like on Facebook should be in one of the 'likes & interests' sections of your profile, all of which have privacy options, for example all of my likes are visible to only friends, and logged out or non-friend users only see this when they view my info tab: http://imgur.com/FE4b0

Comment: Goto the page you described originally (https://www.facebook.com/[username-or-id]/favorites)... there are two sections, the first has the title **Favorites**. If you click the **Edit** button at the top you can change the privacy settings of the Favorites section. There is another section called **Likes**. I cannot find any way to change the privacy of the pages listed in the **Likes** section. If you can find a way please do share.

Comment: Isn't that just a chronological listing of the same information which is summarised / highlighted in the preceding sections? I have (identical) pages which appear in both sections, and when i set the privacy for the section above, it's reflected in visibility of the 'Likes' section (when i check using the 'View As...' feature)

Comment: Apparently I have a reading comprehension problem. You are correct.

Answer (score 0):

You need submit your Facebook App to review, according to [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.5#reference-user_likes)